# Bing Ads PHP API "LocationId: 93 is not supported" for Italy

Tags: php, api, bing-api, bing-ads-api

I am working on Bing Ads PHP API and everything working find for USA, Canada, France and UK. But i am getting error like "LocationId: 93 is not supported." in Italy same for Japan. They have same id in there geolocation csv file for Italy. Please help.

```
Error Code:
The operation failed with the following faults:
OperationError
Code: 622
Error Code: InvalidLocationId
Message: The location id is invalid.
```

Comment: Which methods are you attempting to use that location for? Showing the code might help.

Comment: hey @anyber i am using https://github.com/BingAds/BingAds-PHP-SDK/ this php api. Thing is other countries working good with same api but Italy and Japan giving location id is not supported error.

Comment: But what methods/functions are you attempting to use? The BingAds API is fairly extensive.

Comment: I am using samples/V11/KeywordPlanner.php from that repo. It give volume for provided keywords.

Comment: You may need to contact BingAds support. You could be restricted on your account.

Comment: Thanks i contacted them. They check all everything looking good so they forwarded issue to there developer team. lets see :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [GetKeywordIdeas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingads/ad-insight-service/getkeywordideas), per the [LocationCriterion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingads/ad-insight-service/locationcriterion) doc: "Currently this feature is available in the United States, United Kingdom, Canada, Australia, France, and Germany." BTW this is also in parity with the Bing Ads web Keyword Planner tool.

(Have also answered in the [Bing Ads Developer Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/75f61970-b097-4739-a813-b7515d1f6a50/bing-ads-api-invalidlocationid-error-for-italy-and-japan?forum=BingAds).)

I hope this helps!

Eric